# Postgres trigger inserts all rows

Tags: postgresql, triggers

There are two tables `test.purchase` and `test.stock`.  After filling `test.purchase` with `INSERT` query and 3 triggers which are calculate values in this table, it's last trigger which has to copy by `INSERT INTO` these values from `test.purchase` into `test.stock`.
But after each insert into `test.purchase` trigger inserts ALL rows from `test.purchase` into `test.stock`.
Please advise how to manage insert only last row from `test.purchase` after the query `INSERT INTO test.purchase`

```
CREATE TABLE test.purchase
(
import_id integer,
product_id integer,
usd_price numeric(10,2),
euro_price numeric(10,2),
qty integer,
euro_stock_price numeric(10,2),
expiry_date date,
euro_stock_amt numeric(10,2),
CONSTRAINT id UNIQUE (product_id)
    INCLUDE(import_id),
CONSTRAINT purchase_import_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (import_id)
    REFERENCES test.imports (import_id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT purchase_product_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
    REFERENCES test.products (product_id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TRIGGER tr_purchase_euro_after
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF usd_price
ON test.purchase
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test.fn_purchase_euro_price();

CREATE FUNCTION test.fn_purchase_euro_stock_price()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
UPDATE test.purchase pr
SET euro_stock_price = euro_price + euro_price * i.costs_per_euro
FROM test.imports i
WHERE pr.import_id = i.import_id;
RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_purchase_euro_stock_amount
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF euro_stock_price
ON test.purchase
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test.fn_purchase_euro_stock_amt();

CREATE FUNCTION test.fn_purchase_euro_stock_amt()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
UPDATE test.purchase pr
SET euro_stock_amt = euro_stock_price * qty
FROM test.imports i
WHERE pr.import_id = i.import_id;
RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_purchase_euro_stock_price
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF euro_price
ON test.purchase
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test.fn_purchase_euro_stock_price();

CREATE TRIGGER tr_purchase_stock_plus_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON test.purchase
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test.fn_purchase_stock_plus();

CREATE FUNCTION test.fn_purchase_stock_plus()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO test.stock(
product_id,
stock_qty, 
stock_price, 
stock_amt,
import_id,
expiry_date)
(SELECT DISTINCT
pr.product_id,
pr.qty,
pr.euro_stock_price,
pr.euro_stock_amt,
pr.import_id,
pr.expiry_date
FROM test.purchase pr
);
RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$;

CREATE TABLE test.stock
(
product_id integer NOT NULL,
stock_qty integer,
stock_price numeric(10,2),
stock_amt numeric(10,2),
import_id integer,
expiry_date date
)

INSERT INTO test.purchase(
import_id, product_id, usd_price, qty, expiry_date)
VALUES (2,1,35,100, '12-21-2022');

INSERT INTO test.purchase(
import_id, product_id, usd_price, qty, expiry_date)
VALUES (2,2,35,100, '12-21-2022');

INSERT INTO test.purchase(
import_id, product_id, usd_price, qty, expiry_date)
VALUES (2,3,55,100, '12-21-2022');

beautylabs=# SELECT * FROM test.purchase;
```

| import_id | product_id | usd_price | euro_price | qty | euro_stock_price | expiry_date | euro_stock_amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 35.00 | 28.60 | 100 | 32.84 | 2022-12-21 | 3284.00 |
| 2 | 2 | 35.00 | 28.60 | 100 | 32.84 | 2022-12-21 | 3284.00 |
| 2 | 3 | 55.00 | 44.94 | 100 | 51.60 | 2022-12-21 | 5160.00 |

(3 rows)

```
beautylabs=# SELECT * FROM test.stock;
```

| product_id | stock_qty | stock_price | stock_amt | import_id | expiry_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 32.84 | 3284.00 | 2 | 2022-12-21 |
| 1 | 100 | 32.84 | 3284.00 | 2 | 2022-12-21 |
| 2 | 100 | 32.84 | 3284.00 | 2 | 2022-12-21 |
| 1 | 100 | 32.84 | 3284.00 | 2 | 2022-12-21 |
| 2 | 100 | 32.84 | 3284.00 | 2 | 2022-12-21 |
| 3 | 100 | 51.60 | 5160.00 | 2 | 2022-12-21 |

(6 rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cleary in your proc you are inserting everything in the test.purchase table , if you want to insert newly inserted/updated columns you have to use `NEW`
so for example :

```
CREATE FUNCTION test.fn_purchase_stock_plus()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO test.stock(
product_id,
stock_qty, 
stock_price, 
stock_amt,
import_id,
expiry_date)
VaLUES(
NEW.product_id,
NEW.qty,
NEW.euro_stock_price,
NEW.euro_stock_price * qty, -- replaced stock_amt
NEW.import_id,
NEW.expiry_date
);
RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$;
```

if this is what you want to do

Comment: thank you, but it solve only half of issue, by this statement trigger inserts ONLY fixed date, i.e. `NEW.product_id,
NEW.qty,
NEW.import_id,
NEW.expiry_date`. But calculated `NEW.euro_stock_price,
NEW.euro_stock_amt` are `NULL` (((.  I try to avoid second `UPDATE` trigger to complete table if it's possible.

Comment: What do you mean by fixed date?

Comment: sorry for mistyping.  ... data

Comment: these two columns `NEW.euro_stock_price, NEW.euro_stock_amt` calculated in `test.purchase` by trigger functions as you can see above, so calculated values not transmitted to `test.stock`

Comment: What are the calculations? I don’t see any calculations in your code, but anyways you can play with data and insert whatever makes sense in your trigger function

Comment: you can redo the calculation here for stock table too , see updated answer